# Matching pixel extraction

Tags: qgis, python, raster

I'm trying to optimise some coefficient to compute the chlorophyll-a concentration using Landsat 8.

To do so I need to collect the matching pixels between two rasters but they do not have the same size (I used the filterbounds function in gee but apparently one raster is (608, 231) and the other is (608, 232)).

I can do this in QGIS without any problem but I want to this on Python because I have a lot of image to compare.

Do you know how to bypass this issue?

Two bands on top of each other :
[image]

Output band while dividing one raster by the other :
[image]

My final goal is to create a raster with the matching pixel and the value of each band from the two initial raster

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from QGIS. Set up what you want to do in QGIS, then just before you click `run`, go to `Advanced` in the bottom left corner of the window, and click `Copy as python command`. This will give you the python code to run the command you want. You will need to change the layer names to be variables for it to work on different images in python.

Comment: Hello, when using the raster calculator I don't have this advance button you're talking about.

Comment: Can you please explain in more steps how you filter bounds in QGIS. What steps do you take?

Comment: The filter Bounds function was used in google earth engine. Once done I extracted those images to drive. Then I have imported them on QGis and simply apply rastor calculator on two image to get image 1/image 2 and the output was the matching pixels